# Wordpress getting author's Google+ profile url

Tags: php, wordpress, author

At the author page in wordpress I would like to add the Google+ profile link
of a author.

I know how to add things like site_url, twitter, facebook by the_author_meta('string') but
I don't know the name to show a google+ profile link. I tried 'google' but no luck.

In the documentation of wordpress I can't find anything about Goole+ profile links.

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: You need a plugin or raw HTML

Comment: Example of the html? :)

Comment: `<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/(your ID here)/posts"/>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
the_author_meta('googleplus')
```

Comment: Works! It's **not** returning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code:

```
<?php the_author_meta('gplus_id') ?>
```